# How to eliminate extra matches of element in single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I'm trying to return the mode of an array. I have an inner loop and outer comparing each element to each other. Array = [5,3,6,3,3,3].

```
function mode(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var k = i+1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[k]) { 
            modeItems += arr[k];
            }else {
            otherItems +=arr[i];
        }
    }
}return modeItems;
```

}

Result comes back "333333" instead of "3333". I see how this is happening on an excel sheet comparing the 15 total loops aar[i] and arr[k], but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: take a look as `modeItems`, how it's defined and returned.

Comment: I have it defined as an empty array. My goal was to seperate the matched elements from single instances

Comment: you can do it in `O(nlogn)` time instead of `O(n^2)`

Comment: I'm a new coder, that is Big O notation you're referring to?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/7kp4ens9/

Comment: Yes! I appreciate the help. I working through it to understand. When you have ( modeItems.indexOf(arr[i] < 0 ) . I understand the match is pushed to the empty array, but I'm not following what arr[i] < 0 means. The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. So essentially you're saying if "this item doesn't exist " push to this array otherwise, push to extra items?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a hodgepodge answer. My confusion stems from the title

> How to eliminate extra matches of element in single array

mixed with this part of the question

> I'm trying to return the mode of an array.

---

Reducing an array to an array of single instances, and an array of all duplicates.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/tubofi/1/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
var arra = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];

function simplify(arr) {
  var c = {}, o = [], d = [], i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!c.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
      c[arr[i]] = arr[i];
      o.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      d.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return {
    reduced: o,
    duplicates: d
  };
}

console.log(simplify(arra));
// >> [object Object] {
// >>  duplicates: [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
// >>  reduced: [1, 2, 3, 4]
// >> }
```

---

Removing duplicates from an array in place.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bukabu/1/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];

function elim (arra) {
  var c = {}, i = 0;
  
  while (i < arra.length) {
    if (c[arra[i]]) {
      arra.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      c[arra[i]] = true;
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  return arra; // only required for debug.
}

console.log(elim(arr.slice()));
```

---

Looping that many times on an array just to find the mode is unnecessary. You can use an object literal as a cache to update your counts. If you want an array minus the mode (or an array with only the mode), you can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) afterwards.

Here's a basic implementation. We return null if there is no mode.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/pikece/1/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
function findMode (a) {
  var cache = {},
      len = a.length,
      mode,
      max = 0,
      matched = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cache[a[i]] = (cache[a[i]] + 1 || 1);
    
    if (cache[a[i]] === max) {
      matched = true;
    } else if (cache[a[i]] > max) {
      max = cache[a[i]];
      mode = a[i];
      
      matched = false;
    }
  }
  
  return (matched ? null : mode);
}

var arr = [5,3,6,3,3,3],
    myMode = findMode(arr),
    filteredArr = arr.filter(function (e) {
      return (e !== myMode);
    }),
    modeItems = arr.filter(function (e) {
      return (e === myMode);
    });

console.log(arr); // >> [5,3,6,3,3,3]
console.log(myMode); // >> 3
console.log(filteredArr); // >> [5, 6]
console.log(modeItems); // >> [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

No mode here:

```
findMode([5, 7, 5, 7]); // >> null
```

---

Something slightly more complex. Returns the mode, mode array, and inverse array in two passes of the original array.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kowisu/2/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```js
var findMode = (function () {
  function getMode (a) {
    var cache = {},
        len = a.length,
        mode,
        max = 0,
        matched = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      cache[a[i]] = (cache[a[i]] + 1 || 1);

      if (cache[a[i]] === max) {
        matched = true;
      } else if (cache[a[i]] > max) {
        max = cache[a[i]];
        mode = a[i];

        matched = false;
      }
    }

    return (matched ? null : mode);
  }
  
  function split (arr, mode) {
    var set = [],
        inverse = [];
    
    if (mode !== null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === mode) {
          set.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          inverse.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    
    return [set, inverse];
  }
  
  
  return (function (arr) {
    var mode = getMode(arr),
        lists = split(arr, mode);
       
    return {
      mode: mode,
      set: lists[0],
      inverse: lists[1]
    };
  });
}());


var info = findMode([5,3,6,3,3,3]),
    noMode = findMode([5, 7, 5, 7]);

console.log(info);
console.log(noMode);
```

Comment: Thanks, Oka. I'm trying to run through the more complex example and comment it to see how and why this works. Im confused on a few parts.

Comment: [This](http://jsbin.com/lomoca/1/edit?js,console) might help. Some minor edits, and explanations. Keep in mind this only really works on arrays of either all strings or all numbers, since object properties are *always* strings. `cache[55]` and `cache['55']` are the same property. You can solve this by having caches for each type. This will *never* work on arrays containing objects (or arrays), as object's will be cast to the same `'[object Object]'` string, and it won't work if our mode is *actually* `null`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working matching , for every number in the loop , the numbers after the index `i+1` :

```
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
   ^   ^       //first match
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
   ^     ^    // match 2
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
   ^       ^  // match 3
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
       ^ ^    // match 4
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
       ^   ^  // match 5
[5,3,6,3,3,3]
         ^ ^  // match 6
```

a simple way to work around this issue would be to reset loop with `continue` if `i` has already been matched; but it would fail if you had multiple double occurrences..

Comment: i would like to account for that test case

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an object array for keeping processed items and ignore the item in the next iterator that are already processed.

```
function mode(arr) {
var processed = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[k]) {
            modeItems += arr[k];
            modeItems += !processed[arr[k]] ? arr[k] : '';
            processed[arr[k]] = i;
            break;
        } else {
            otherItems += arr[i];
        }
      }
  }
  return modeItems;
}

Output: 3,3,3,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me also add my two cents. This code delete matched items to don't use it again :)

```
function mode(arr){
   var key = arr[0],       // it wil be the mode, current value of array
        count = 1,          // it will be the count of mode value
        icount;
        for (var i = 0;  i < arr.length-count+1; i++) { // there is no need to look any further - 
                                                        // count is more then rest items

            if (!arr[i]) continue;
            icount = 1;
            for (var k = i+1; k < arr.length; k++) {
                if (!arr[k]) continue;
                if (arr[i] == arr[k]) {  icount++; delete arr[k]; }
            }
            if (icount > count) { count = icount; key = arr[i]; }
    }
    if (count == 1) ret = null;  // At this moment key - mode. Below output
    else {  var ret = []; while(count--) ret[count] = key; ret = ret.join();}
    return ret; 
 }
```

Comment: i thought that by deleting an element ( in the code that I originally posted ), would alter the results by "shifting the index" position relative to whats left to search.

Comment: No, i print indexes. they not changed, unfortunatly. But the code work. More important to do for to arr.length-(count-1). Ii really decreases loops count